# Objective-C. Maintain and upgrade old project, so it could be putted in to the AppStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I was send an old xCode project with app builded for iOS 4.3. What bothers me, that this project has multiple bundles within it and multiple files for loading each bundle with files in the xCode. As far as I know, thouse days, there was a such approach of coding - to split project in to the smaller projects. My goal is to change interface and put this project in to the AppStore.

I wonder:

- Is it possible to make needed changes and send the project to the App Store as it is(multiple bundles with code files and launch files for xCode). If not, what should be done to accomplish this?
- In the case if it is possible to send this project as it is - is there a way to convert all xib files from all bundles to one storyBoard?

Would be glad to hear answers and ofcourse some tips/advises from people, who are familiar with this situation.

P.S. By clicking the link, you can take a look how does the whole project folder looks. Every folder in the project folder has the same hierarchy as on the picture.
http://s11.postimg.org/n6j9kmr9f/Screen_Shot_2015_02_28_at_18_33_01.png

Comment: Isn't that a usual project?

Comment: Every folder that you see: JanisRozeAkcijas, JanisRozeKontakti, JanisRozeTops and etc - have the same hierarchy as opened one(screen shot). They all have a file appName.xcodeproj. I never saw something like that. I always worked with one xcodeproj file for the whole project. So, I am confused.

Comment: But there is one project that contains all of them as subprojects (or only some of them and others contain the other projects), right? If so this is not uncommon. Xcode builds all the subprojects when it builds your app and compiles all of them into one binary.

Comment: Yes, this is how it is - project with several sub projects. I just didn't experienced working with such approach. Is it a common approach nowadays also? I wonder, if it is possible to add a storyboard instead of xib files and will all those sub projects work with one storyboard.

Comment: No. I'm fairly certain you can't share storyboards between projects, and it would be a very bad idea to do so.

Comment: Of course you can add a storyboard. All classes that are used in one of the subprojects can be used in the parent project (and in your storyboards). It's actually quite common (and since iOS 8 also for iOS) to create subprojects for your self-written dynamic frameworks.

Comment: Remember the old saying: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Changing it around to use storyboards rather than XIBs would be a large, error-prone job. Refactoring it so that it is one project rather than several would be another large, error-prone job. It's more important to make sure that it uses ARC, and to take a look at what deprecated APIs it's using.

Comment: There is no easy way to convert XIB files to a Storyboard. But if your app compiles cleanly and you've tested it thoroughly for 32-bit/64-bit compatibility then you should be able to submit to the AppStore. If your app is quite old make sure you read the Apple docs on converting to 64-bit especially if you use pointer arithmetic or write out files. Going forward you might want to convert to static libraries and definitely convert to ARC.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and putting me on the right path!